# RxJS - BehaviorSubject, onComplete not called

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm building an Angular 7 app and using BehaviorSubject to keep the user authentication state as it's recommended on every source on the internet.

Since BehaviorSubject is an Observable, why can't I fire the onComplete() method?

Here's the code (which seems pretty classic to me):

```
this.authService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
      this.isLoggedIn = state;
    },
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('complete')
    );
```

authService

```
authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

'complete' is not logged. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**

```
this.authService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
      this.isLoggedIn = state;
      this.authService.authenticationState.complete();
    },
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('complete')
    );
```

then the complete() method is fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can trigger complete like this when you are ready for the complete section of the subscription to be called.

```
authenticationState.complete();
```

Answer (score 3):

`complete` is only called when an Observable is done emitting items. IOW it's the last event from a non-erroneous Observable.

If you're only interested in a single item from this Observable you could:

```
authenticationState.first().subscribe();
```

This way the `complete` will be called after the single emitted item.